# Is there TensorFlow C++ API for parsing TFRecord file?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there anything equivalent to [`tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/python_io/tf_record_iterator) and [`ParseFromString()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#graphdef) function? Googling and looking at TensorFlow repo didn't turn up much.

Answer (score 0):

Each entry of TFRecord is organized in the below way (you can verify this via [record_writer.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/516ae286f6cc796e646d14671d94959b129130a4/tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.h) in tensorflow repository)

```
class RecordWriter {
 public:
  // Format of a single record:
  //  uint64    length
  //  uint32    masked crc of length
  //  byte      data[length]
  //  uint32    masked crc of data
  static constexpr size_t kHeaderSize = sizeof(uint64) + sizeof(uint32);
  static constexpr size_t kFooterSize = sizeof(uint32);
```

and the whole TFRecord is just a repeat of above structure.

- For two `crc` field, you may skip them (carefully)
- For the `length` field, you can read 8 bytes into uint64_t variable in C++
- For the `data` field, it is actually serialized Protocal Buffer `message`

The format of `message` is described in [example.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) in tensorflow repository, and you can compile it with corresponding version protoc and get the API to decode the serialized `data`.

A more detailed explanation and corresponding code are given in my [github](https://github.com/initzhang/TFRecord-Parser), you can give it a try :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are in any way or form affiliated with the plugin/website/blog/product/project etc that you have linked then please mention your affiliation clearly in the answer itself.
Undisclosed affiliation will be considered spam and deleted. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).